# How to control door opener from raspberry pi?

Tags: pi-4, python-3

I am trying to control a 6V DC door opener which requires 660 mA current supply. Since the Pi only tolerates a maximum of 5V without a relay. As per my research I need a solid-state relay with transistor. These are specification of door opener which I am using
Current consumption DC (50% residual ripple)12V, current consumption DC (50% residual ripple)6V, current consumption DC (stabilized)12V 1300mA, current consumption DC (stabilized)6V 660mA.

I have question how much volt of relay will be required depends on which criteria.

Comment: learn from both tutorials ... asking which tutorial to follow is not a question about Raspberry Pi, so it is off topic here

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You can buy, instead of DIY a relay module.

Comment: @tlfong But I have a dout what are therequirement for choosing ow much volt the Realy should be. If my Pi is already connected to one other crcuit which is supplying 5V for further reading.

Comment: @Jen, I would suggest newbies to learn this way: (1) Buy a 5V High level triggered relay module, (2) Try switch on/off a LED, (3) Try switch of/off a 12V motor. (4) You are almost there.  (5) Part A of my TLDR answer to the following question might help:  https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry. Happy learning.  Cheers.

Comment: @Jen Most cheap relay modules you find are rated for 10A.  I'm not sure why you need a solid state relay, aside from not hearing it when it activates.  As tlfong01 stated, get some and play with them.

Comment: @rtaft I need solid state relay for accessing the door opener.